# Why are /30 subnet used for PPP connections?

Tags: ipv4, subnet, adsl, ppp

Our telephone company has recently set us up a new ADSL connection.
It consists of a PPP link over ATM.

The connection comes with a public /30 subnet that we can use to our liking.
We used one of the IP addresses for standard NAT, and one of the addresses for remote router access (ports 22 and 443) and port forwarding to a server (ports 4000-5000).

It also uses a public /30 subnet for the PPP link, one IP for each endpoint.

I don't understand why:

- A /30 subnet is used for the two public IP addresses. Couldn't they just route our two IP addresses over our PPP link as isolated addresses that don't belong to any subnet? If my understanding is correct, this would allow them to effectively double the amount the number of "address couples" they can sell.
- A public subnet is used for the PPP link. Why is this the case? Since these IP addresses aren't publicly routed anyway, but only used by the two routers for the PPP link, isn't this a waste of the public address space?

Comment: You did not use one IP address for NAT and another for remote router access as you have only 1 usable IP address.  Please correct your facts.

Comment: What do you not understand exactly? There are two subnets, one for the PPP (not publicly routed, one IP for the remote ISP router, one IP for my location's router) and one publicly router subnet at my disposal (one IP for the NAT, one IP for router management and port forwarding). Could you stop downvoting everything for you own personal lack of understanding? That's just immature.

Comment: Riccardo, now you got me confused as well: the question says `A public subnet is used for the PPP link` but your comment says `one [subnet] for the PPP (not publicly routed)` ? Maybe it would help a lot if you could add a visual network diagram.

Comment: I'm in Paris from the weekend, I'll do that as soon as I'm home. Anyway, what I mean is that the PPP subnet uses addresses from a public range, but they are *not* publicly routed (i.e. you can't ping one of those addresses from the Internet, they are just in use for the PPP link subnet).

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti Your question is no good as it is and deserves to be downvoted.  Don't take it personally.  You can edit the question and, ... who knows how many upvotes it could get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A /30 subnet is used for the two public IP addresses. Couldn't they
>   just route our two IP addresses over our PPP link as isolated
>   addresses that don't belong to any subnet? If my understanding is
>   correct, this would allow them to effectively amount the number of
>   "address couples" they can sell.

Well the way I see it is that they route 4 public IP addresses to you, and you decide whether to use them as one /30 subnet or as two /31 subnets or as 4 individual (/32) IP addresses - or even a combination of one /31 and two /32.

In other words if your ISP says they're routing the 10.0.0.0/30 *subnet* to you then they actually mean that they're routing the  *ip address range* 10.0.0.0-10.0.0.3 to you.

Edit: adding an example to (hopefully) clarify further for those that do not understand.
Assume this scenario:

```
ISProuter (a.b.c.1) ----- (a.b.c.2) MyRouter
```

ISProuter has a route for x.y.z.4/30 with next-hop a.b.c.2

Then on MyRouter I have roughly 4 options:

1. I configure x.y.z.5 on one of my interfaces, with a /30 subnet mask. In that case I can only use x.y.z.6 on another device (since .4 and .7 are the network and broadcast addresses in this scenario)
2. I configure 4 loopback interfaces with x.y.z.4, x.y.z.5, x.y.z.6 and x.y.z.7, each with a /32 subnet mask
3. I use x.y.z.4/31 and x.y.z.6/31 on 2 point-to-point links.
4. I route x.y.z.4/30 to another router, and on that router I have again the same 4 options.

Note: there are also combinations possible, e.g. I could use x.y.z.4/32 on a loopback, route x.y.x.5/32 to another router, and use x.y.z.6/31 on a p2p link.
And depending on the features available on MyRouter (which could also be a load balancer, or a firewall, or...) the addresses could also be used without actually configuring them on an interface, but the result would be very similar to using them as /32's on a loopback.

> A public subnet is used for the PPP link. Why is this the case? Since
>   these IP addresses aren't publicly routed anyway, but only used by the
>   two routers for the PPP link, isn't this a waste of the public address
>   space?

You would need to ask the ISP, we can only guess. I guess most ISPs consider it best practice to use public IP addresses for public links. Private IP address might break stuff like PMTUD as ICMP from the 2 PPP endpoints would probably get dropped in a lot of places. But as @RonMaupin mentioned, they could have used a public /31 instead to save some address space.

Comment: That makes sense, I hadn't thought of it that way before. I guess that's because the ISP is managing my router, and they just set it up to route the IPs as a /30 subnet, and they set up NAT to the local network on the second IP and router management and the 4000-5000 port forwarding on the third.
Out of curiosity, how should I ask them to configure the router if I wanted, for example, to be able to route the four single IPs myself with a firewall setup such as pfSense? (i.e., configure the router in such a way that the pfSense machine would "have" those four IPs on its network interface)

Comment: Ok I partly misunderstood the setup then, I thought you were in control of the router. It depends on how they have configured it exactly. If they just have used 2 addresses for NAT, they should be able to create two /32 routes to your firewall for the 2 unused addresses. If you want them to remove the config using the 2 addresses then they can just route the /30 to your firewall (and it's up to you whether to treat it as a /30 or as 4 individual addresses), however then the last leg of the public path (outside the firewall) will be using private addressing (which would work,but see question2).

Comment: So - if I'm understanding correctly - the ISP's router and my firewall should be in a privately routed subnet (possibly with public addresses, like they do it for the PPP link), with e.g. addresses 10.0.0.1/30 and 10.0.0.2/30, and the router would need to be configured to statically route my publicly routed /30 to 10.0.0.2/30, and my firewall should be configured to NAT inbound from my publicly routed /30 (possibly using it as four indipendent /32s) to whatever local addresses/ranges I need, and to NAT outbound using 10.0.0.1/30 as the gateway, right?

Comment: @hertitu your statement "they route 4 public IP addresses to you, and you decide whether to use them as one /30 subnet or as two /31 subnets or as 4 individual IP addresses." is wrong.  The broadcast address and the network address in a /30 mean you have 2 usable IP's.

Comment: That's not true, that's exactly what hertitu was trying to explain. The subnet is routed entirely to my router, without any concept of network address or broadcast address. Now, let's say this subnet is 20.20.20.0/30. If I physically route that subnet to a network of four interfaces assigning 20.20.20.0/30, .1/30, .2/30 and .3/30, the first and the last will not make sense and the middle two interfaces will receive packets for .3/30. But if you assign the four addresses as /32s to the interfaces, there will be no network and broadcast addresses at all and everything will work fine.

Comment: In other words, the behavior you talk about is implemented in the network interfaces. If you route the subnet in a way that all four IP addresses physically deliver the packets to the interfaces, you can just configure the interfaces to behave as you please by changing the subnet mask.

Comment: @RonRoyston: please check Riccardo's comments above, and the edit I made to my answer and let us know if you still think it is wrong (and if so, why).

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti: in answer to your "So - if I'm understanding correctly": yes that is what I had in mind.

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti OK, what IP address (with subnet mask please) do you point your Internet traffic to?

Comment: @RonRoyston He already said so: `...using 10.0.0.1/30 as the gateway`. In the example I edited in, the default route points to a.b.c.1. What is your point?

Comment: Wrong his question does not say so.

Comment: @RonRoyston Indeed his question did not say so, but his comment did. Again, what is your point?

Answer (score -4):

The public IP addresses issued by the ISP's enable customer to have Internet routing, for example Skype or gaming - types of communication where endpoints need to communicate directly with one another.

The /30 preserves public IP addresses.

Comment: Actually, `/30` wastes half the public addresses compared to using `/31`, which has been around since the year 2000 in RFC 3021 for point-to-point links.

Comment: If think you are confusing "public IP address" with "publicly routed IP address". IP addresses for the PPP link don't enable customers to do anything. They are a technicality that allow PPP to be used as a tunnel between two routers. This is why I'm wondering why they are using public IP addresses instead of private ones. Publicly routed IP addresses, instead, enable customers to have Internet routing, which by the way it isn't at all required by Skype or gaming, a NAT setup is enough for that. What I don't understand is why my ISP implements this service in a way that seems wasteful to me.

Comment: ISP is not doing your NAT for you, they provide you a public IP address.  You can NAT it, or if you want several devices to have Internet access in your home, you can PAT it.  PPP provides a mechanism for security purposes.

Comment: Why is my answer wrong / downvoted?  I am eager to learn!  What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti your comment that "Internet routing, which by the way it isn't at all required by Skype or gaming," is wrong.  Also, "IP addresses for the PPP link don't enable customers to do anything." is wrong.  Also, "They are a technicality that allow PPP to be used as a tunnel between two routers." is wrong.  Pretty much everything you have said is wrong and I answered your question.

Comment: @RonMaupin appreciate your input but the OP asked about a "connection [that] comes with a public /30 subnet" and never mentions a /31.  But again, thanks for chiming in to my answer.  You might move the comment to the OP's question, however.

Comment: It sounds like you misread or misinterpreted the questions as well as some of the comments. Scenario is R1 --ppp-- R2 ---- R3/FW. Why do you think that the statement `IP addresses for the PPP link don't enable customers to do anything` is wrong? . If either R2 or R3 does NAT using a public IP address then why would the PPP link need public IP addresses as well???  So I really don't understand how your answer applies to the OP's questions. In addition, your `The /30 preserves public IP addresses` is wrong since a /31 would preserve more space (and so RonMaupin's comment is in the right place)

Comment: @hertitu `IP addresses for the PPP link don't enable customers to do anything` OK, say there is no IP address.  Customer now has no Internet routing capability - right or wrong?

Comment: We didn't say the PPP link doesn't need ip addresses. We said it doesn't need *public* ip addresses.

Comment: Dude, ISP's dont give out private addresses but OK, for you @hertitu let's pretend like they do.  OK, remove the private IP address.  Customer now has no Internet routing capability - right or wrong?

Comment: ok I'm 1 step away from giving up, since this discussion is pointless if you don't at least TRY to understand the question and the comments and if you insist on continuing to twist our words around. And please don't call me "dude".

Comment: As with many of your answers, what you say is correct but completely beside the point. The question is not "would the ppp link work without ip addresses?". The question is "would the ppp link, which now uses public ip addresses, work just as well with private ip addresses?". And we're not talking about "giving out private addresses", we're talking about a PPP link administered by the ISP. The ISP then gives out a public /30 which is routed over the ppp link.

Comment: @RonRoyston I'm sorry my question wasn't clear enough for you. It sure isn't posed in the best way possible. I'm currently abroad for work and then I'll begin the process of moving house. I'll be sure to improve it as soon as possible. However, I think the main points were pretty clear, and it really saddens me to notice that instead of trying to understand them you are just bashing on me and hertitu and repeating the same thing again and again.

Comment: "_Dude, ISP's dont give out private addresses..._" I guess you missed the whole CGN thing. It's a hot topic over on [su]. Residential customers are complaining in droves that they can no longer run servers from their homes because they cannot forward ports on the carrier NAT, even though the residential ISP agreements almost always include a provision prohibiting that.